# Redshift Stored Procedures not passing dates properly

Tags: date, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I notice Redshift changes my date to '2001'. Run the below for a very clear simple example

Result3 is correctly today's date (which is 2019-11-07). However Result2 (the stored procedure) simply returns '2001'. I've tried casting as well as passing the date in differently but the result stays the same. Any recommendations?

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pub.test_sp1(IN param date,INOUT tmp_name varchar(256))
AS $$
DECLARE 
  row record;
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'drop table if exists ' || tmp_name;
EXECUTE 'create temp table ' || tmp_name || ' as
select ' || param;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CALL pub.test_sp1(current_date, 'myresult');
SELECT * from myresult;

select current_date
```

Comment: It was doing math: `2019 - 11 - 7 = 2001`

Answer (score 0):

```
EXECUTE 'create temp table ' || tmp_name || ' as select ' || param;
```

is transformed (after concatenating the strings and substituting the values) to

```
EXECUTE 'create temp table myresult as select 2019-11-07'; -- => select 2001
```

Don't concatenated values this way, use `quote_ident()` and `quote_literal()` for proper quoting:

```
EXECUTE 'create temp table ' || quote_ident(tmp_name) || ' as select ' || quote_literal(param);
```

or with the `format()` function:

```
EXECUTE format('create %I as select %L', tmp_date, param);
```

---

As an example:

```
#= SELECT 'test: ' || current_date as incorrect, 
          'test: ' || quote_literal(current_date) as correct;
┌──────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│    incorrect     │      correct       │
├──────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ test: 2019-11-07 │ test: '2019-11-07' │
└──────────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you so much!